# SSRS Report Query - BETWEEN within WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report that I am creating that shows various counters collected on some SQL servers over the last several months. I have the report working, however I want to add an enhancement, but can't quite figure out how to do it.

Basically, I want to query my "Performance Stats" table, and only select records that are between 2 dates specified in the report. I also want to further reduce that amount by hours of the day, based on a parameter. For example, I would like to be able to select all records from 01/01/2014 thru 01/02/2014 and it will return all those records into a graph I have defined.

Furthermore, I would then like to have a dropdown box, where the report user can pick the hours of when the CPU counter was recorded, such as "Business Hours Only" (8:00am - 5:00pm) or "Outside Business Hours Only" (5:00pm - 08:00am) or even both.

**EDIT:**

OK - I've got the script working with the below:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
DECLARE @DateThru DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Hours INT = 1

SELECT  Stat_Datetime ,
        cntr_value
FROM    Admin.dbo.PerformanceCounters
WHERE   object_name = 'Processor'
        AND Stat_Datetime BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateThru
        AND ( 1 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@Hours, ''))
              AND ( (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00'
                                                 AND     '17:00') )
              OR ( 2 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@Hours, ''))
                   AND ( ( CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) >= '17:00' )
                         OR ( CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) < '08:00' )
                       )
                   OR ( 1 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@Hours, '')) AND 2 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@Hours, '')))
                 )
            )
ORDER BY stat_datetime
```

However when SSRS executes it, the function returns an error:

```
Msg 8144, Level 16, State 3, Line 6
Procedure or function dbo.fnSplitString has too many arguments specified.
```

This is how SSRS is executing it (from profiler):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  Stat_Datetime ,
        cntr_value
FROM    Admin.dbo.PerformanceCounters
WHERE   object_name = ''Processor''
        AND Stat_Datetime BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateThru
        AND ( 1 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(1,2, ''''))
              AND ( (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) BETWEEN ''08:00''
                                                 AND     ''17:00'') )
              OR ( 2 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(1,2, ''''))
                   AND ( ( CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) >= ''17:00'' )
                         OR ( CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) < ''08:00'' )
                       )
                   OR ( 1 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(1,2, '''')) AND 2 IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(1,2, '''')))
                 )
            )
ORDER BY stat_datetime',N'@DateFrom datetime,@DateThru datetime',@DateFrom='2014-08-13 00:00:00',@DateThru='2014-11-13 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get everything working without the split function by just doing this:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
DECLARE @DateThru DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Hours INT = 1

SELECT  Stat_Datetime ,
        cntr_value
FROM    Admin.dbo.PerformanceCounters
WHERE   object_name = 'Processor'
        AND Stat_Datetime BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateThru
        AND ( 1 IN ( @Hours )
              AND ( (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00'
                                                 AND     '17:00') )
              OR ( 2 IN ( @Hours )
                   AND ( ( CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) >= '17:00' )
                         OR ( CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) < '08:00' )
                       )
                 )
            )
ORDER BY stat_datetime
```

Thanks for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try & take the reference from below script..

```
SELECT *
FROM
(    
SELECT   Stat_Datetime ,
        cntr_value,
        CASE 
        WHEN Stat_Datetime BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Stat_Datetime , 110) + ' 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)
                     AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Stat_Datetime , 110) + ' 17:00:00' AS DATETIME) THEN 'BH'
        WHEN Stat_Datetime BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Stat_Datetime , 110) + ' 17:00:00' AS DATETIME)
                     AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Stat_Datetime, 110) + ' 08:00:00' AS DATETIME) THEN 'OBH'                     
        END AS 'BHours'
FROM    Admin.dbo.PerformanceCounters
WHERE   object_name = 'Processor'
)Result
WHere BHours IN('BH','OBH')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Without testing this, I can't be sure - but would this work for the case when the user ticks both BH and OBH?

Comment: use split function in query for multi select option (parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare var @hours as int with 3 states possible
DECLARE @Hours INT

@Hours:

BH - 1

OBH - 2

BH or OBH - 3--both

```
AND (@Hours = 1 
    AND (
        (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '17:00')
        )
OR (@Hours = 2
    AND (
        (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:00' AND '08:00')
        )
    )
OR (@Hours = 3)--both
```

Comment: This looks like it would work quite well actually. I can just change the parameter values to integers, that's easy. I'll test and let you know :)

Comment: I just had a thought - what if the user selects all 3 options? (1 both or all). I would need to use @Hours LIKE '%1%'? I used to have a function that iterated through a multi-valued parameter, but can't remember it...

Comment: In that scenario you can use dropdown. If you would like to use dropdown box you need to implement split function (TSQL or CLR) which returns TABLE. Then you can join with that result set.

Comment: Here you can find how to implement it in TSQL: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Comment: OK I got this to work, but had to do this - (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) >= '17:00') OR (CAST(Stat_Datetime AS TIME) < '08:00'. How can I get the multi-value parameter to work? So if the user ticks both BH and OBH the parameter will return (1, 2) ?